# springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin not generating output file when used with spring.webflux.base-path

Tags: spring-webflux, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a maven Spring Boot project that uses Webflux. I generate the open api spec into an output file using `springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin` in my pom:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
       <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
   <configuration>
       <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
       <outputFileName>openapi.json</outputFileName>
       <outputDir>${project.basedir}/target</outputDir>
   </configuration>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <id>integration-test</id>
           <goals>
               <goal>generate</goal>
           </goals>
       </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

I also added the `springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui` dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

The above setup was working all fine and a new `openapi.json` file was generated each time I compiled.

However, I had a need to add a prefix for all my API paths. So I ended up adding a `spring.webflux.base-path` property in my `application.yml` file, which worked as expected.

```
spring:
  webflux:
    base-path: "/myproject"
```

Once I did this, open api was not able to generate the output file (`openapi.json`) anymore. Is this expected? Is there a way to debug open api related errors?

Comment: are you able to solve it?